# How find the value $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}(C_{3k}^k)^{-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, summation

find the value 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{C_{3k}^{k}}$$

and  long ago,I have see this and is easy
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{C_{2k}^{k}}$$

where 
$$C_{n}^{k}=\dfrac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}$$

Comment: The standard notation for $C^k_n$ is $\binom{n}{k}$, these are binomial coefficients.

Comment: Yes,@Ethan,Thank you

Comment: At Mathworld (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialSums.html) there are evaluations of such sums as $$\sum_1^{\infty}2^{-n}{3n\choose n}^{-1}$$ with a pointer to Borwein, J., Bailey, D., and Girgensohn, R., Evaluation of binomial series, §1.7 in Experimentation in Mathematics: Computational Paths to Discovery, A K Peters, pp. 20-28, 2004.

Comment: Also worth a look is Cheon and Mansour, Rational combinations for the sums involving inverse binomial coefficients, available at http://math.haifa.ac.il/toufik/toupap11/q11ap2011_24.pdf

Comment: oh,Thank you my frend @GerryMyerson

Answer (score 9):

We can write
\begin{align}
S=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{3k \choose k}^{-1}&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma(k+1)\Gamma(2k+1)}{\Gamma(3k+1)}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kB(k,2k+1)=\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k\int_0^1x^{k-1}(1-x)^{2k}dx=\\
&=\int_{0}^1\frac{(1-x)^2dx}{\left[1-x(1-x)^2\right]^2}=\\
&=\int_{0}^1\frac{x^2dx}{\left(1-x^2+x^3\right)^2}.
\end{align}
The integrand in the last expression is a rational function of $x$. Therefore the antiderivative can be calculated using standard methods in terms of rational functions and logarithms and the result will be expressed in terms of the roots of the cubic equation $x^3-x^2+1=0$.

---

**UPD**: Added the actual value:
$$S=\frac{4}{23}-\frac{2}{23}\sum_{k=1}^3\frac{\left(x_k+3\right)\ln(1-x_k)}{3x_k^2-1},$$
where $x_{1,2,3}$ denote three solutions of the cubic equation $x^3-x+1=0$.

Comment: +1. Likewise, the identity $\sum\limits_{n\geqslant1}{2n\choose n}^{-1}=\int\limits_0^1\frac{x\mathrm dx}{(1-x+x^2)^2}$ yields the value of $\sum\limits_{n\geqslant1}{2n\choose n}^{-1}$.

Comment: @Did What I find curious is that the sum $\sum_k x^k/{3k \choose k}$ is given by some $_3F_2$ function. In the beginning I unsuccessfully tried to reduce it to an elementary function using some known identities. But apparently, the above trick allows one to do it much more easily.

Comment: Note that ${}_3F_2$ functions are characterized by the ratio of successive coefficients being $P(n)/(nQ(n))$ with $P$ of degree $3$ and $Q$ of degree $2$. For the coefficients ${3n\choose n}^{-1}$, the ratio is $R(n)/Q(n)$ with $R$ and $Q$ of degree $2$, which is also $P(n)/(nQ(n))$ with $P(n)=nR(n)$ hence $P$ of degree $3$. Ergo.

Comment: @Did Of course, the appearance of hypergeometry is not a surprise. The surprise is its reduction to elementary functions.

Comment: Ahhh... I see. Indeed.

Answer (score 2):

For #2:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{C_{2k}^{k}}=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{2\pi}{9\sqrt{3}}$$

Because,

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{C^n_{2n}}=\frac{4(\sqrt{4-x}+\sqrt{x}\arcsin(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}))}{\sqrt{(4-x)^3}}$$

Which is because
$$\text{If we set, } A_n=\frac{1}{C^{n}_{2n}}$$
Then
$$(4n+2)A_{n+1}=(n+1)A_n$$
And so,
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(4n+2)A_{n+1}x^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+1)A_nx^n$$

So that if $$A(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty A_nx^n$$

$$\frac{d}{dx}A(x)-\frac{x+2}{x(4-x)}A(x)=\frac{-2}{4x-x^2}$$

Now with some work you can verify $A(x)$ satisfies the above differential equation.

For #1:

Likewise

If you let $K_n=\frac{1}{C^n_{3n}}$

And,

$$F(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{C^n_{3n}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty K_nx^n$$

We have that, $3(3n+1)(3n+2)K_{n+1}=2(n+1)(2n+1)K_{n}$

So,
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty 3(3n+1)(3n+2)K_{n+1}x^n =\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2(n+1)(2n+1)K_{n}x^n$$

And so that we get,

$$4x^2\frac{d^2}{dx^2}F(x)-17x\frac{d}{dx}F(x)-\frac{4}{1-x}=0$$

Which is a second order linear ordinary differential equation, and can be solved in terms of elementary functions, namely in terms of logarithms and inverse tangent functions.

Once you have $F$, then just compute $$F(1)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{C^n_{3n}}$$

Comment: Presumably the question not only wants to know the sum of the series but some explanation for the fact that the sum has that value.  «Can be evaluated in terms of hypergeometric functions» does not mean a lot, really: in fact, the sum **is** a value of a hypergeometric function. How knowing that helps us at all?

Comment: And how did you find that number? Explaing *that* would be an answer, even if you got the value out of a table.

Comment: Why dont you write **words**, sentences, in your answer? Explain things! You are interacting with humans here, remember that.

Comment: Where did the first equation come from? $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{C^n_{2n}}=\frac{4(\sqrt{4-x}+\sqrt{x}\arcsin(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}))}{\sqrt{(4-x)^3}}$$

Comment: OK, and now to the question asked in the post, which is $\sum\limits_n1/{3n\choose n}$, not $\sum\limits_n1/{2n\choose n}$.

Comment: Thank you,@Ethan,the second one is very old,and I have some methods,but first one I can't find .

Comment: @downvoters Care to elaborate why you downvoted? I provided answers to both his questions which is better then NO answer, if you don't like my answer post your own.

Comment: I honestly do not see what might be the reason behind the downvotes, really...

Comment: The second order ODE needs some rewriting (even though the method is sound). And note that the effectivity of the method depends on the ability to solve this ODE...

Comment: Then, to explain why one can be sure that the ODE is solvable in terms of elementary functions might help (once the ODE itself is corrected).

Comment: ((Some comments by the OP now deleted.))

Comment: @Did I think I fixed it now

Comment: There are some mistakes in the computations, for example tha factor of $F''(x)$ is $4x^2-27x$.